# tspans added dynamically do not appear correctly relative to one another in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I'm trying to display tspans dynamically. the usual use case is that it can be added anywhere on a line so long as the dx/x and dy values are set correctly once added.

This works fine in Firefox (29) but not in Chrome (35)

It does work when the tspans are added in the correct order from the beginning but this will not be the real use case so i can't count on that

i have created a small test page. with three cases:
adding the text hardcoded in the html, dynamically like the real use case and dynamically in order. in the developer tools of chrome the DOM is exactly the same (unless i missed something) but only the first and third cases are displayed correctly.

here is a link to the jsfiddle exampele: http://jsfiddle.net/X7t2s/1/

```
var text = document.getElementById("textDOM");

//in the real use case this is here first
var t2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","tspan");
t2.textContent = "i";
t2.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb(0,0,255)"); 
t2.setAttributeNS(null,"dy","12pt"); 
t2.setAttributeNS(null,"x",0);
text.insertBefore(t2,null);

//we then add this as first
var t1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","tspan");
t1.textContent = "H";
t1.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb(255,0,0)"); 
t1.setAttributeNS(null,"dy","12pt"); 
t1.setAttributeNS(null,"x",0);
text.insertBefore(t1,t2);

//because t1 has been added we remove x and set dx and set dy
t2.setAttributeNS(null,"dy","0");
t2.removeAttributeNS(null,"x");
t2.setAttributeNS(null,"dx",0);
```

Am i doing something horribly wrong ?
I this a bug in Chrome ? If so is there a workaround ?
Since the SVG DOM appears correct is there a way to force it to redraw so that hings are displayed in the correct order ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it looks like you have struck a bug in Chrome.  I did a little experimenting myself and found that adding and removing a `<tspan>`s is flaky.

You should probably report this as a bug.  Go to `Tools->Report an issue` or https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: thank you for taking the time to experiment. i've added this as bug like you said. I will wait a bit more to see if the bug gets confirmed/ or someone comes up with a workaround before i pick this as accepted answer